# Python Multi-threading with sockets hangs on first function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I am building an application that uses sockets in order for a client to act as a client and a server at the same time. To do so I uses the "threading" python library to "listen" and "speak" simultaneously. 
The problem is that when the first thread that is targeting the "listening" function starts, the program waits for inbound connection and the second thread targeting the "sending" function never actually launches.
So my question is **how can I listen and speak at the same time ?**
I have looked up this issue here but could not find a suitable solution so here I am.

```
    def listen():

        addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        port = 30000

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((addr, port))
            s.listen()
            conn, address = s.accept()

            with conn:
                addr, port = address

                while True:
                    try:
                        data = conn.recv(4096)

                        print("New message: {}".format(data.decode()))
                    except ConnectionResetError:
                        print("Connection has been interrupted.")
                        break

    def send(addr: str):

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            try:
                s.connect((target, self.port))
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                print("Cannot reach host {}".format(target))
                exit()

            while True:
                content = str(input("Message: "))

                try:
                    s.sendall(content.encode())
                except ConnectionResetError:
                    print("Connection has been interrupted.")
                    exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = threading.Thread(target=listen())
    y = threading.Thread(target=send())

    x.start()
    y.start()
```

Comment: You call the functions instead of passing them to the thread. It should be ``target=listen`` instead of ``target=listen()``, and same for ``send``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that instead of *passing a function* as the `target` argument to `Thread`, you're *calling the function* (`listen()`, `send()`).  The function then never returns.

So replace this:

```
x = threading.Thread(target=listen())
y = threading.Thread(target=send())
```

with this (parenthesis omitted):

```
x = threading.Thread(target=listen)
y = threading.Thread(target=send)
```